# What kind of OMF do I ask for from my Editor?

Tags: omf, editing, post-production, workflow

Hey Everybody,

I worked on a feature over the past summer and now its time for me to do post on the film.
The editor gave me an OMF but when I went to a buddies house to import it into Pro Tools, none of the audio files were there. What should I ask for from my editor in order to start my work and what I should always expect when being handed off something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OMF comes in two flavours, *Embedded* and *External Referenced*; Embedded OMF creates copies of all the media files and keeps it contained within the file, Referenced (what you've been given) contains only metadata.

You could just ask for the media files and then relink all the data.

Embedded OMF has a limitation that no file within it can be over 2GB, Referenced doesn't have this problem. Important to know depending on the size and type of project you're working on.

Answer (score 3):

sounds like you need to ask for the omf to have "embeded audio." it still wants to link to the original audio currently. the omf settings should included "embeded audio" and "linked video". OMF 2.0

also, ask for long handles on the audio. when making the omf, they have options regarding embedding media and creating handles.

Answer (score 1):

As Brendan & Brad have outlined you need at embedded OMF.

I have free help guides on my site which outline how to create Pro Tools friendly OMFs from both Avid and FCP.

Go to http://www.osd-uk.com/free-help-guides/ and choose the guide you want.

Mike